# How do I run Microsoft Code Writer as Administrator?

Tags: windows-10, administrator, runas

When I right click on the Microsoft Code Writer icon, there is no option to "Run as Administrator"

Comment: Running UWP applications as Administrator isn’t necessary.  Even if the option was provided UWP permissions cannot be elevated in that manner.

Comment: @Ramhound I have files that only editable with the Admin privileges. How do I use Code Writer to edit those files, if can't run Code Writer as Admin?

Comment: Besides the host file on Windows.  Where are these files located that you don’t have write permissions to.  Regardless of what file it is, escalating an UWP application, will not result it being able to write to a protected directory.  There are specific and purposeful restrictions on UWP applications.  Use a different text editor, specifically a desktop Win32 application, for those files that require elevated permissions

Comment: @Ramhound many applications that are installed as Administrator, have XML / JSON based config files that are only editable with Admin privileges.

Comment: If you required Administrator permissions to modify a configuration file.  I would argue the file is being stored in the incorrect location.  Configuration files like that should be stored in the AppData directory within the user's profile.  All that said, it does not really matter if there is a reason it's required, UWP applications installed from the Windows Store can't modify those files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If [Code Writer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/code-writer/9wzdncrfhzdt) is strictly a UWP (a.k.a. Microsoft Store) application, you won't have the option to `Run as administrator`.

Sources:
[UWP app elevated privileges](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94485bfa-3937-47b3-a6b2-b04c418c246b/uwp-app-elevated-priviledges?forum=win10itprosecurity)
[Run UWP app with elevated rights](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/3513693b-b210-4f8c-a47a-17505a8f39fd/run-uwp-app-with-elevated-rights?forum=WindowsIoT)